# rails fields_for render partial with multiple locals producing undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, locals

All,

I am experiencing a problem with a standard fields_for setup.  In my "_form" partial I have:

```
<div class="comment_list">
  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |cf| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment_fields', :locals => {:f => cf, :tester => true} %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add a comment", f, :comments %>
</div>
```

In the "_comment_fields" partial, I have the usual fields and then my test variable:

```
<%= tester.to_s %>
```

When I remove the tester variable, everything works well.  As soon as I add the test variable, I get this error:

> *ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `tester' for #Class:0xa1f3664>:0xa1f1bd4>)*

Has anyone else ran into this problem when using a fields_for with multiple locals?

---

To elaborate a bit more, my "_comment_fields" partial looks like this:

```
<div class="comment dynamic_field">
  <span class="comment_content"><%= f.text_field :content, :class => "comment_content" %></span>
  <%= tester.to_s %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</div>
```

It is only called from the "_form" partial.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't rendering comment_fields in more than one place? If you are, can you paste comment_fields?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only rendering comment_fields from the _form partial.  The problem only occurs when I try to pass more than one local variable.

Comment: hakunin - you were right on this one. I was actually calling it from two places.  The second place was within some methods which I use to dynamically add fields using javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All,

[Hakunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155351/hakunin) was on the money.  I was calling the partial in more than one spot.  The second spot was in my helper method "link_to_add_fields."  I use this to add fields using javascript.

The method looked like this:

```
# generates add fields on a dynamic form
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, locals={})  
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new  
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, 
                      :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)  
  end  

  link_to(name, "#", :class => "dynamic_add", 'data-association' => "#{association}",
                                            'data-content' => "#{fields}")
end
```

Notice that this does not allow any locals to be passed to the render method.  I changed it like so:

```
# generates add fields on a dynamic form
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, locals={})  
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new  
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, 
                      :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", locals.merge!(:f => builder))  
  end  

  link_to(name, "#", :class => "dynamic_add", 'data-association' => "#{association}",
                                            'data-content' => "#{fields}")
end
```

Now my link_to_add_fields call in my _form partial looks like this:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add a comment", f, :comments, :tester => true %>
```

...and I can dynamically add fields to my form AND pass additional locals.  Hopefully, this will help someone else out.

Comment: Amazing, I also had a `link_to_add_fields` helper method that was causing this exact problem! Thanks for posting your answer!

Comment: That's great never thought that the link_to_add_fields is causing the error :D

Comment: `klass.new` should now be `build_association` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass

Comment: Sorry, reading further: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AbstractReflection/build_association

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/comment_fields', :locals => {:f => cf, :tester => true} %>
```

to :

```
<%= render 'comments/comment_fields', :locals => {:f => cf, :tester => true} %>
```

I just had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that was my original issue way back then... I also think the two statements you have above are equivalent because render without arguments defaults to using a partial...
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear why do you need to use tester variable in form field. But can you please paste a code how are you using tester variable in partial form.

I strongly believe that

```
<%= tester.to_s %>
```

should not generate any issue as it only displays a value of that variable

Comment: The tester variable is just that... a test.  In the above, a comment belongs to an Article.  The article belongs to an Account. What I really want to do is pass in the Article's account.  My locals actually looks something like:  :locals => {:f => cf, :account => article.account}.  Unfortunately, this was not working and I was receiving the "undefined variable" error.  As part of my debugging, I simplified with this "tester" variable.  As you have mentioned, it should not generate an issue.  This is the problem.